# tensorFlowJs Json model issue

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter, tfjs-node

trying to get a custom tensorFlowJS model to work in JS but getting error with the shape, kindly note that the model is already trained and converted to model.json  but getting below error

> Error: Error: Error in concat4D: Shape of tensors[1] (1,30,40,256) does not match the shape of the rest (1,15,20,832) along the non-concatenated axis 1.

below is the code:

```
const RGB = await imageToRgbaMatrix(imageUrl);
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(modelUrl);
const ImageData =  await tf.tensor([RGB]);
const predictions = model.predict(ImageData);
```

in brief i am trying to implement the tfjs model (model.json) with binary file with it gives:

> Error in concat4D: Shape of tensors[1] (1,30,40,256) does not match the shape of the rest (1,15,20,832).

Comment: Is the input image of same size as what the model is trained on ?